# What does the "rcs" option in ar do?

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, static-linking, unix-ar

I did read the man file but it does not help. `rcs` seems to be the most popular option to pass to ar, but the meaning isn't so clear to me.

So `c` means to create a new archive, but then why use `r`? which seems to stand for "replace"? What will the `s` option do to the output?

Comment: http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rcs1.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Reading the [manual page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ar) (for ar) is a good start:

> c
>
> Create the archive.    The specified archive is always created if  it
>   did not exist, when you request an update.  But a warning is issued
>   unless you specify in advance that you  expect  to  create  it,  by
>   using this modifier.
>
> r
>
> Insert the files *member*... into archive  (with  replacement).  This
>   operation  differs  from  q in that any previously existing members
>   are deleted if their names match those being added.
>
> s
>
> Write  an object-file index into the archive, or update an existing
>   one, even if no other change is made to the archive.     You  may  use
>   this modifier flag either with any operation, or alone.  Running "`ar s`" on an archive is equivalent to running [ranlib](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ranlib%201) on it.

Comparing with [POSIX](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ranlib%201), you may notice one difference: GNU ar makes the "-" prefixing options optional in itself.

An archive *can* contain other items than object-files (though this is not done often). Archives containing object-files require additional maintenance (e.g., done by `ranlib`) to make them usable by the linker.

According to the *[Rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ar.html#tag_04_03_18)* in POSIX ar, the `-s` option originated in BSD (System V *did* this automatically). However, running `ranlib` by itself is the prevailing practice (`-s` is rarely used).  Interestingly enough, POSIX does not have `ranlib`, and ultimately the `-s` option will replace `ranlib` in the multitude of makefiles which were written to run on a variety of platforms.

Answer (score 25):

Reading the manual for `ar` helps but I will explain it in more detail.
`ar -rcs` is the most likely command you would use when using a `Makefile` to compile a library.
`r` means that if the library already exists, replace the old files within the library with your new files.
`c` means create the library if it did not exist.
`s` can be seen to mean 'sort' (create a sorted index of) the library, so that it will be indexed and faster to access the functions in the library. 
Therefore, `rcs` can be seen to mean `replace, create, sort`.

Answer (score 4):

This means "Insert the files member... into archive (with replacement)."